# regex redirect "/service" IIS 7

Tags: regex, redirect, iis-7, sitecore, web-config

I am new to .NET and IIS ans I am trying do a regular expression redirect with this pattern `\/([^\/]+)(?=\/[^\/]+\/?$)` so my url wil go from `mysite.com/en/solutions/exemple` to `mysite.com/en/exemple` but in the redirection IIS put /Service in my URL someone as a idea how to fix this?

here is the rule generated in my `web.config` by IIS 7

```
 <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="redirect salesforce" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="\/([^\/]+)(?=\/[^\/]+\/?$)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/en/{R:0}/coveo-for-salesforce" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

Thanks
```

UPDATE:I tried

```
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
      <rule name="remove solutions from url" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([^/]+)(/[^/]+)(/.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:0}{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
   </rewrite>
```

I get a not not found

Please note that I am working on a Sitecore solution with 2 languages en and fr

Comment: So, you want to remove the `/solutions/` part of the URL?

Comment: exacly but as a 301 redirect at the same time

Comment: Have you tested the solution below using IIS Rewrite module tester or by typing the urls in the browser?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove the first level folder from the url, e.g.:

> /en/solutions/example-page -> /en/example-page
>
> /en/other-folder/another-page -> /en/another-page
>
> /fr/one-more-folder/blah-page -> /fr/blah-page

with the 301 redirect code, use the following rule:

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="remove solutions from url" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([^/]+)(/[^/]+)(/.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}{R:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

If you want to redirect with `301` code from `mysite.com/en/solutions/exemple` to `mysite.com/en/exemple` (so in fact remove `solutions` from all urls (but only if they are directly after language), you can use:

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="remove solutions from url" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^([^/]+)/solutions(/.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I've tested the solution on Sitecore application and it definitely works.

Comment: yes but the thing is it could be plateforme instead of solution I have other path but I alway want the result to be mysite.com/en/exemplepage

Comment: I have a the input does not match the pattern by IIS

Comment: Answer updated. See if it helps. If not, edit your question and provide few exampes.

Comment: same thing I have a error for /en/solutions/exemple

Comment: Have you copied the second rule only with the match `"^([^/]+)(/[^/]+)(/.*)"` ? What is the full url? What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Please remember that when testing the pattern in IIS Manager you don't use the first `/` character so you need to test `en/solution/exemple` instead of `/en/solution/exemple`.

Comment: I tried your regex pattern ^([^/]+)/solutions(/.*) at http://regexpal.com/ and they do not work on mysite.com/en/solutions/exemple and it does not work

Comment: You need to know that for each language, regex syntax is different. You can not use javascript regex tester (which regexpal.com is) to test IIS Rewrite module expressions. Just put the code from my answer in web.config and try to access url.

Comment: I did already and it did not work, With this one ^([^/]+)/solutions(/.*)  I am getting a error "document's was not found". Same with the other pattern

Comment: Do you have an item in Sitecore called `exemple` directly under the `en` home item? If there is no one, you will get 404 even if redirect works.